# NSNotification not observing or posting data

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, nsnotificationcenter

I am trying to learn how to use NSNotification for a project I am working on, and since I have never used it before, I am first trying to learn how to use it first, however; every time I try to follow a youtube tutorial or a tutorial found online my code doesn't seem to be working. Also, when trying to debug the issue, it is showing the observer part of the code isn't going inside the @obj c function. Below is my code showing how it is being used to post and observe a notification.

```
    extension Notification.Name {
    static let notifyId = Notification.Name("NotifyTest")
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
    }

    var test: ObserverObj = ObserverObj(observerLblText: "Observing")
    @IBAction func notifyObserver(_ sender: Any) {
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ObserverVC")
        vc?.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        guard let vcL = vc else {
            return
        }
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .notifyId, object: nil)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vcL, animated: true)
    }
    
}
```

NotificationTestViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class NotificationTestViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var observerLbl: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(observingFunc(notification:)), name: .notifyId, object: nil)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    @objc func observingFunc(notification: Notification) {
   
        observerLbl.text = "notifying"//text.test.observerLblText
    }
```

Can someone help me and let me know where I am going wrong as I've been trying for 2 days.

Comment: First of all your example is pretty non-practical because you could pass the data directly. Most likely the reason is that the notification is posted before the observer has been added. Add print lines to figure it out. Notifications are only useful if sender and receiver are not directly related or there are multiple receivers.

Comment: I know the reason why notifications are useful, which is why I need them. Also, I am only trying to practice how to use it first before applying. I've been adding print lines to see where I am going wrong but I still don't see what I'm doing that's causing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notification is sent before the observer is added, that means `viewDidLoad` in the destination controller is executed after the `post` line in the source view controller.

Possible solutions are :

1. Override `init(coder` in the destination controller and add the observer there.

   ```
   required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: coder)
       NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(observingFunc), name: .notifyId, object: nil)
   }
   ```
2. If `init(coder` is not called override `init()`
3. Add the observer before posting the notification (this solution is only for *education* purpose)

   ```
   @IBAction func notifyObserver(_ sender: Any) {
       guard let vcL = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ObserverVC") as? NotificationTestViewController else { return }
       vcL.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
       NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(vcL, selector: #selector(NotificationTestViewController.observingFunc), name: .notifyId, object: nil)
       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vcL, animated: true) 
       NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .notifyId, object: nil)
   }
   ```

However in practice you are strongly discouraged from sending a notification to a destination you have the reference to.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that when you send out a notification, your `NotificationTestViewController` has not yet called the `viewdidload` method

```objectivec
  class ViewController: UIViewController {
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
            
        }

        var test: ObserverObj = ObserverObj(observerLblText: "Observing")
        @IBAction func notifyObserver(_ sender: Any) {
            let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ObserverVC")
            vc?.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            guard let vcL = vc else {
                return
            }
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vcL, animated: true) 
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .notifyId, object: nil)
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, however; I don't understand, how do I call the viewDidLoad method. When I move the code to the viewDidLoad Method I still get the same issue.

Comment: You don't call it. The `UIViewController` calls it after it loads the view. However even though this answer has reversed the order of the lines, I doubt that the view is loaded when the notification is posted. You could force view loading by calling `vcL.loadViewIfNeeded()` or you could use a `dispatchQueue.main.async` to slightly delay the posting of the notification.